# How to share wireless in Xubuntu

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, sharing

Just wondering. How do I share an ethernet connection through wireless in Xubuntu. in windows I could use Intel MyWifi Technology but I'm not sure about linx's software

Comment: @poolie - suggest raise your own question clearly indicating that the two "dupes" are not applicable in your situation.

Comment: @fossfreedom I don't have a question about this.  My comment was in reply to your earlier and now deleted comment.